# Android: Program type already present: com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat

Tags: android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I've develop a project using [zxing](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded) to scan the barcode. I had followed the tutorial from [here](https://www.loopwiki.com/application/android-qr-code-scanner-barcode-scanner/), but unfortunately I got error when I tried to run the project to device. The error that I get is

[image]

This is the **build.gradle(app)**

```
dependencies {
     implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
     implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
     implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

     // volley
     compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'

     // butter knife
     compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
     annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

     // picasso
     implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

     // QR Zxing Library
     implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'
}
```

Below is **External Libraries** list.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project?

Comment: @C.Carter same error even after clean and rebuild project.

Comment: Try restarting Android Studio. Just tested this and it worked fine for me. Can always do a search through the whole project for cases of ZXing in case it's accidentally defined somewhere else

Comment: @C.Carter still got same error even after restart the pc. Ya maybe. Hmm I checked the External Libraries, ZXing library have 2 (core and embedded), I update the question to show the image for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day I tried to find out the solution, but everything failed. Then I decided to create a new project and copy the current source code together with build.gradle(app). Luckily no more error occurred when I run new project.

But I still don't know what the actual reason why I got that error before this, so I assume maybe some part of the old project are missing or have some bug on it.

Answer (score 0):

Because at new project you change buildToolVersion 
Reason : Its happened because being conflict between core.jar and zxing 
Solution : Just change buildToolVersion and build , after that revert old toolVersion and build again !

Answer (score 0):

After weeks of searching, the following steps help me resolve the issue like a charm:

1.Remove android platform.
2.Install cordova-plugin-facebook4
3.Create build.gradle in /plugins/cordova-plugin-facebook4/
4.Copy this

dependencies {
compile("com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.37.0") {
exclude group: 'com.google.zxing'
}
}

to ../plugins/cordova-plugin-facebook4/build.gradle
5.Edit ../plugins/cordova-plugin-facebook4/plugins.xml change

to

6.Add platform android and build